# $l(D)$ for algebraic curve in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and plane divisor

Tags: calculus, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be smooth algebraic curve of degree $7$, embedded in  $\mathbb{CP}^2$ which is a curve defined by one polynomial in two variables. Let $D = p_1+p_2 + \cdots +p_6$ and let all $6$ points lie on the same complex line.

What is $l(D)$, the dimension of vector space of meromorphic functions on $C$, which have no simple poles outside D. Let $K$ stand for canonical divisor.

$l(K)=g$, $g = \frac{5 \cdot 6}{2} =15$, $deg D = 6$, 
$l(0)=1$,

By Riemann-Roch theorem we get that $l(D) = l(K-D) - 8 \leq 7$.

The situation is that we have $L(0)$ which is one-dimensional, and as we add points to the divisor we get more and more functions, so the dimension rises by no more than 1 with each point. But since all the points are on the same complex line, we can't be sure that every time the dimension rises. How should I use the fact that all the points are on the same plane?

I have got this task on my Riemann surfaces exam last spring. I am allowed to use any theorem or fact.

Comment: Did you try using the fact that a "hyperplane" section $H$ of $C$ will contain these $6$ points and $1$ more? So considering $H-D$ might be fruitful.

Comment: @TedShifrin No I didn't, but I don't get the thing, $H-D$ is one point, how can it help?

Comment: Well, it's only one point when you take one particular hyperplane section. I'm just suggesting considering that linear system. I haven't worked it out.

Comment: @TedShifrin do you mean that we can consider a hyperplane lynear system? I.e. all divisors linearly equivalent to the hyperplane section?